# Forcing a Function to Integrate to 1

Tags: probability, integration

I always always been interested in learning about how to make my own Probability Distribution Function.

For example, suppose I want to make a Probability Distribution Function that looks like a triangle and has a peak at 0.5. This would look something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0.5, 1, 0), y = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "grey") +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("P(X)") +
  ggtitle("Trianglular Probability Distribution: X vs P(X)") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I also know how to define this mathematically as a piece-wise function:

$$P(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
x & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 0.5, \\
 -x + 1 & \text{if } 0.5 < x \leq 1.
\end{cases}$$

However, there are some evident problems with this:

- There is no way of guaranteeing that this function integrates to 1
- This is a piecewise function and I do not think that a Probability Distributions can be defined in terms of piecewise functions

**My Question:** Is it possibly to take the work I have done and somehow modify it such that it becomes a valid probability distribution and integrates to 1?

Thanks!

**Related Question:**

- [Calculating the Probabilities of a 100-Sided "Weighted" Dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804927/calculating-the-probabilities-of-a-100-sided-weighted-dice)

Comment: Your code and plot (slope $\pm 1$) don't match your formula (slope $\pm 2$).

Comment: @ aschepler: thank you for pointing this out - I will revise this right now

Comment: You measure the grey area in your graph above (using classical geometry in this case, or an integral for more complicated distributions) and get $A = \frac 12 bh = \frac 14.$   Now you have some choices, make the peak higher, or the base wider, or some combination of both.

Comment: There is no problem having a piecewise density.  You do the integration and then rescale, so your $2x$ on $[0,\frac12]$ and $2(1-x)$ on $(\frac12,1]$ integrates to $\int_0^{1/2}2x\,dx+ \int_{1/2}^1 2(1-x)\,dx=\frac14+\frac14=\frac12$ so you have to double everything to reach an integral of $1$, giving a density for your triangular distribution of $4x$ on $[0,\frac12]$ and $4(1-x)$ on $(\frac12,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: In fact triangular distributions are well-known. The sum of two i.i.d. uniform continuous random variables has a triangular distribution.

Comment: @ Henry: thank you so much for your reply! I did not know this about piecewise functions

Comment: here is a related question I asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804927/calculating-the-probabilities-of-a-100-sided-weighted-dice

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate the function over its domain.

In your case, since the function is piece -wise, it will be integrated piece wise.

Your function can be integrated using geometry (area under the curve). Using the standard formula for area of a triangle, it is
$$\frac{1}{2}hb=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times1=\frac{1}{4}$$

Since you would like to make the area 1, you multiply the function by 4(reciprocal of 1/4).

In general, this is called the process of normalizing the function.

Note: I have used your graph, and not your piece wise function to answer. The two do not match. For example, 2x at 0.5 is 1, but the graph shows 0.5

Comment: Indeed, *normalizing* a thing generally means scaling it to unit magnitude. In the case of a vector **v**, we normalize it by dividing it by its norm $||{\bf v}||$. Not to be confused with the term *normal*; two vectors are normal to one another if their inner product is zero.

Comment: @Starlight: Thank you so much for your answer! I have update the equation and graph - is this better?

Comment: Will this still result in a valid probability distribution function?

Comment: Once you normalize, yes, it results in a probability distribution. Normalization is a common process. For example, refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizing_constant

Comment: @Starlight: thank you so much for your reply! I want to make this triangle as a probability distribution function .... but the corresponding function is a piecewise a function. I have never seen a probability distribution that is written as a piecewise function. Is this possible?

Comment: here is a related question I asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804927/calculating-the-probabilities-of-a-100-sided-weighted-dice