# Proving the Memoryless Property ONLY Applies to Exponential Distributions

Tags: probability, proof-writing

\begin{equation} 
\quad  P(X > s + t | X > s) = P(X > t) \quad  \text{for all $s, t \geq 0$} \quad 
\end{equation}

The [Memoryless Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness) (above) of the Exponential Distribution means that if you have already waited $s$ minutes for the bus - the probability that the bus comes in $s+t$ minutes .... is the same as if you only waited $t$ minutes. Unfortunately, the amount of time $s$ you have already waited does not count.

Here is my attempt to show the Memoryless Property applies to the Exponential Distribution using Cumulative Distributions and Conditional Probability Law:

\begin{equation}
\text{Exponential PDF:} \quad f(x; \lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{Exponential CDF:} \quad  P(X \leq x) = F(x; \lambda) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{1 -  CDF:} \quad  1 - P(X \leq x)  = P(X > x) = e^{-\lambda x}
\end{equation}

Using Law of Conditional Probability:

\begin{equation}
P(X > s + t | X > s) = \frac{P(X > s + t \text{ and } X > s)}{P(X > s)} = \frac{P(X > s + t)}{P(X > s)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(X > s + t | X > s) = \frac{e^{-\lambda (s + t)}}{e^{-\lambda s}} = e^{-\lambda t} = P(X > t)
\end{equation}

**My Question:** In my classes, we were told again that the Memoryless Property ONLY applies to the Exponential Distribution - **I am curious as to why it ONLY applies to the Exponential Distribution**. I am able to show that this applies to the Exponential Distribution (i.e. above) - **but how do I show that the Memoryless Property ONLY applies to the Exponential Distribution?** (e.g. not other distributions)?

As an isolated example, I tried to verify that the Memoryless Property DOES NOT apply to the Gamma Distribution, but this was quite complicated:

$$ \text{Gamma PDF:} \quad  f(x; k, \theta) = \frac{x^{k-1}e^{-x/\theta}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)}$$
$$ \text{Gamma CDF:} \quad  F(x; k, \theta) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\gamma(k, x/\theta)$$

If I try to use these definitions within the Memoryless Property:

$$\frac{\int_{s+t}^{\infty} f(x; k, \theta) dx}{\int_{s}^{\infty} f(x; k, \theta) dx} = \int_{t}^{\infty} f(x; k, \theta) dx$$

$$\frac{\int_{s+t}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-1}e^{-x/\theta}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)} dx}{\int_{s}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-1}e^{-x/\theta}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)} dx} = \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-1}e^{-x/\theta}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)} dx$$

I am not sure how to prove that the above relationship is not true in general. I know that for a Gamma Distribution, when $k=1$, the Gamma Distribution becomes an Exponential Distribution - therefore, the above relationship (memoryless property) will be true for when $k=1$. However, I do not know how to prove that that when $k \neq 1$, the above relationship will not be true. And even if I did understand this, I would have to show that the Memoryless Property does not apply to all other distribution (e.g. Weibull, etc.) - and this would involve proving it for the generic distribution.

- **Can someone please help me understand why the Memoryless Property does not hold in the case of the Gamma Distribution?**
- **And more generally, can someone please help me understand that why the Memoryless Property ONLY holds for the Exponential Distribution?**

Thanks!

**Update:** I tried to present a proof of this question over here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4807952/791334

Comment: The complimentary cumulative distribution needs to satisfy $G(t+s) = G(t)G(s),$ so its logarithm is an additive function with some regularity properties. Then, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: Actually, there's a similar argument [on the wikipedia page you linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness#The_memoryless_distribution_is_an_exponential_distribution)

Comment: @ spaceisdarkgreen: thank you so much for your reply! Can you please help further understand your comment about the additive function and the cauchy equation?

Comment: I saw this section in the wikipedia link : "The memoryless distribution is an exponential distribution" . While I could somewhat sense that this argument is indirectly rereferring to the point that the Memoryless Property is only valid for the Exponential Distribution - I did not fully understand how this argument supports this. I thought maybe some mathematical proof needs to be written involving Characteristic Functions and Mathematical Induction? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Memorylessness means the function $G(t) = \ln(1-F_X(t))$ satisfies the Cauchy functional equation $G(t+s) = G(t)+G(s).$ The Cauchy functional equation page explains that the only monotonic functions satisfying this equation are of the form $G(t) = At$ for constant $A.$ This, together with boundary conditions, implies that $F_X(t) = 1- e^{-\lambda t}$ for some $\lambda>0.$

Comment: thank you so much for these clarifications! I will try to spend the week teaching myself about this and trying to understand the relationships between these....

Comment: No problem. The part about Cauchy functional equation isn't that bad really... you show first that the values are fixed on the integers once you choose $G(1)$ (which will be the constant multiplier $A$), e.g. $G(2) = G(1)+G(1) = 2G(1)$, and then extend that logic to show it is given by $G(x) = G(1)\cdot x$ on the rationals. Then if it is continuous (or monotonic), it will have to be squeezed to follow the same equation on all the real numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. If you have time this week, can you please show me how to write a proof for this? I am also working on the integral for the gamma distribution. Thank you so much!

Comment: I would only write something very similar to what's written on the Memorylessness wikipedia page (which is very close to what I sketched in my last comment, but doesn't bother with taking the log... just shows $H(x) = 1-F(x)$ satisfies $H(x) = H(1)^x$ by showing the functional eqn $H(x+y) = H(x)H(y)$ determines it to be so on the rationals). If you have any questions on it, feel free to ask here or in a follow-up question.

Comment: @  
spaceisdarkgreen : I actually tried to prove this result myself over here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807907/proof-involving-cauchy-equation - can you please take a look at this?

Comment: This is another math puzzle I am working on - can you please take a look at it if you have time? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804927/calculating-the-probabilities-of-a-100-sided-weighted-dice thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

OP here, this my own attempt to prove this (I am citing a previous answer I wrote https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4807952/791334):

I tried to approach this proof using concepts from Survival Analysis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis)

**Part 1:** Typically, we say that the Survival Function is given by $S(t) = P(x>t) = 1 - F(t)$.

In the case of the Exponential Distribution, the Survival Function is given by : $S(t) = P(x>t) = 1 - F(t) =   e^{-\lambda t}$

The law of conditional probability tells us that $P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ . If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A) *P(B)}{P(B)}$ . We can apply this law for $P(x>s+t | x>s)$ :

$$ P(X>s+t | x>s)  = \frac{P(x>s+t \cap  x>s)}{P(x>s)} = \frac{P(x>s+t) }{P(x>s)} =  \frac{S(s+t) }{S(s)}   $$

Note that $P( x>s)$ is implicitly contained within $P(x>s+t)$. This is because the probability of surviving time $s+t$ implies that a minimum of time $s$ has already been survived.

**Part 2:**

(A) If the Memoryless Property were to hold, then:

$$P(X>s+t | X>s) = P(X>t)$$

and
$$S(s+t | s) = S(t)$$

(B) But in general (whether the Memoryless Property is true or not true, does not matter):

$$P(X>s+t | X>s) =   \frac{P(x>s+t \cap  x>s)}{P(x>s)}  = \frac{P(x>s+t )}{P(x>s)} $$

and

$$S(s+t | s) =   \frac{S(s+t \cap  s)}{S(s)}  = \frac{S(s+t )}{S(s)} $$

Now, equating (A) and (B) :

$$ S(t) =  \frac{S(s+t )}{S(s)} $$
$$S(s+t) = S(s)*S(t)$$

**Part 3:** Using the relationship $S(s+t) = S(s)*S(t)$, we can take the natural logarithm on both sides:

$$ln[S(s+t)] = ln[S(s)*S(t)] = ln[S(s)] + ln[S(t)] $$

If we now take the derivative of both sides with respect to $s$:

$$ \text{LHS:} \quad  \frac{d}{ds} \ln[S(s+t)] = \frac{S'(s+t)}{S(s+t)} $$
$$ \text{RHS:} \quad  \frac{d}{ds} \ln[S(s)] + \frac{d}{ds} \ln[S(t)]  = \frac{S'(s)}{S(s)} $$

Since $ \text{LHS = RHS}$, then:

$$\frac{S'(s+t)}{S(s+t)} = \frac{S'(s)}{S(s)} = c \quad \text{where c is some constant, e.g.,} \quad  c = - \lambda$$

Now, we integrate the above equation with respect to $s$:

$$\int \frac{S'(s)}{S(s)} \, ds = \int -\lambda \, ds$$

$$ ln[S(s)] = - \lambda * S$$

$$ S(s) = e^{ -\lambda * s} $$

And $S(s) = e^{ -\lambda * s}$ is the survival function of the Exponential Distribution. This means that only a distribution with a Survival Function of $S(s) = e^{ -\lambda * s}$ would satisfy the Memoryless Property. And I think that only the Exponential Distribution will have a Survival Function of $S(s) = e^{ -\lambda * s}$.

Ideally, this would have concluded the proof.

However, am not sure if this is a valid proof - for example, perhaps some other probability distribution $g(x)$ might somehow share the same survival function ... but I am not sure how to proceed.